# SQL JOIN - return a row for each Table A, regardless if Table B has values or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below query that should return a row for every Reading_Type, plus either the saved Reading value for that Reading_Type and date, or 0 if no Reading has been saved.

```
SELECT
      t.*
    , ISNULL(r.Reading, 0) AS Reading
FROM
    Reading_Type t
LEFT JOIN
    Reading r ON t.Reading_Type_ID = r.Reading_Type_ID
WHERE
    r.Reading_Date = @date
    OR r.Reading_Date IS NULL
```

- It *does* work if there are no Readings saved for any date
- It *does* work if the only Readings saved are for the selected date.
- It does *not* work if a Reading_Type has a saved Reading for date X, no saved Reading for date Y, and the search is for date Y.

`Reading_Type` Table:

```
Reading_Type_ID  Reading_Type
-----------------------------
1                Red
2                Blue
3                Green
```

`Reading` table (table is empty):

```
Reading_ID  Reading_Type_ID  Reading  Reading_Date
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Query with `@date = April 15, 2016` returns:

```
Reading_Type_ID  Reading_Type  Reading
----------------------------------------
1                Red           0
2                Blue          0
3                Green         0
```

`Reading` table (table has data for April 15):

```
Reading_ID  Reading_Type_ID  Reading  Reading_Date
-----------------------------------------------------
1           1                5        April 15, 2016
2           3                8        April 15, 2016
```

Query with `@date = April 15, 2016` returns:

```
Reading_Type_ID  Reading_Type  Reading
----------------------------------------
1                Red           5
2                Blue          0
3                Green         8
```

Query with `@date = April 7, 2016` returns:

```
Reading_Type_ID  Reading_Type  Reading
----------------------------------------
1                Red           0
3                Green         0
```

The third query should still return a row for Reading_Type = Blue, with 0 for Reading.  How do I fix my query?

Comment: maybe there is no Reading_Type for April 7, 2016?

Comment: @FLICKER I think that's sort of the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your WHERE criteria is causing your filter problem (done this myself only a million times or so). Try this instead:

```
SELECT
      t.*
    , ISNULL(r.Reading, 0) AS Reading
FROM
    Reading_Type t
LEFT JOIN
    Reading r ON t.Reading_Type_ID = r.Reading_Type_ID
AND r.Reading_Date = @date
```

Leave out the WHERE clause in this instance (unless you want to further filter your data).

Here's some information which helps detail this SQL feature: [Specifying Joins in FROM or WHERE clauses](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213235(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: This is a LEFT JOIN, meaning it will pull every record from the table Reading_Type. The OP used a WHERE clause which did filter that out. However, by moving the criteria into the JOIN clause, all the records from the LEFT table will be returned plus all the records which match in the RIGHT table. If there is no match, a NULL is return which is set to 0 by the ISNULL() function of the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

if r.Reading_Date can be null and you want to include those then

```
SELECT t.*, ISNULL(r.Reading, 0) AS Reading
FROM Reading_Type t
LEFT JOIN Reading r 
       ON r.Reading_Type_ID = t.Reading_Type_ID
      AND isnull(r.Reading_Date, @date) = @date
```

Answer (score -1):

The query is doing what you're asking it to. It's doing a left join (which will return all records from `t` and records from `r` if/when these exist)... then it applies your where condition. In the case that `r.Reading_Date` is neither `NULL` nor `@date` then, the records from that query will be excluded from the result set.

I think what you want, if I've understood correctly, is a left join on a subselect... so something more like this:

```
SELECT
  t.*, ISNULL(r.Reading, 0) AS Reading
FROM
Reading_Type t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Reading_Type_ID, Reading 
    FROM Reading
    WHERE Reading_Date = @date
    OR Reading_Date IS NULL
) r
ON t.Reading_Type_ID = r.Reading_Type_ID
```

Comment: It was yeah, I posted mid edit, by mistake... corrected.